# using llvm RecursiveASTVisitor for Objective C and iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, clang, llvm

I would like to use clang to preprocess objective C files from an iOS app.  I looked over the source code and am trying to implement a pre-processor based on the RecursiveASTVisitor class.  However, I seem to be running into many issues that I cannot resolve.  I developed a preprocessor to add a "Enter" call at the beginning of each method and an "Exit" call at the end.  I also added an "Exit" call before each return statement.  I am using the following code to do the instrumentation:

```
class ExampleVisitor : public RecursiveASTVisitor<ExampleVisitor> {
private:
    ASTContext *astContext; // used for getting additional AST info
    std::string funcName;

public:
    explicit ExampleVisitor(CompilerInstance *CI)
    : astContext(&(CI->getASTContext())) // initialize private members
    {
        rewriter.setSourceMgr(astContext->getSourceManager(), astContext->getLangOpts());
    }

    virtual bool VisitObjCMethodDecl(ObjCMethodDecl *ND) {
        funcName = ND->getDeclName().getAsString();
        errs() << "Testing function: " << funcName << "\n";
        if (ND->hasBody()) {
            rewriter.InsertText(ND->getBody()->getSourceRange().getBegin().getLocWithOffset(1), "\nEnter(\""+funcName+"\");\n");
            rewriter.InsertText(ND->getBody()->getSourceRange().getEnd(),"Exit(\""+funcName+"\");\n");
        }
        return true;
    }
    virtual bool VisitReturnStmt(ReturnStmt *ret) {
        rewriter.InsertText(ret->getSourceRange().getBegin(), "\nExit(\""+funcName+"\");\n");
        errs() << "** Rewrote ReturnStmt\n";
        return true;
    }

    virtual ~ExampleVisitor() {}
 };



class ExampleASTConsumer : public ASTConsumer {
private:
    ExampleVisitor *visitor; // doesn't have to be private

public:
    // override the constructor in order to pass CI
    explicit ExampleASTConsumer(CompilerInstance *CI)
    : visitor(new ExampleVisitor(CI)) // initialize the visitor
    { }

    // override this to call our ExampleVisitor on the entire source file
    virtual void HandleTranslationUnit(ASTContext &Context) {
        /* we can use ASTContext to get the TranslationUnitDecl, which is
         a single Decl that collectively represents the entire source file */
        visitor->TraverseDecl(Context.getTranslationUnitDecl());
    }

};
```

The code compiles.  I created a command line executable "instrument".  I then used the following command to run this on a simple Objective C program generated by Xcode:

instrument AppDelegate.m --

I run into two problems.  First, I get the error: 'UIKit/UIKit.h' file not found.  This is one of the includes generated by Xcode.  Second, I'm seeing only some of the return statements being processed in the file.  Can someone give me some insights into what is happening?

I'm using the 3.7.0 version of llvm.

Comment: Just to get a better idea what you are trying to achieve here:

- I presume by "generated" by Xcode you are referring to the boilerplate/template code included when creating a new iOS project there?

- Since you are using clang and your classes take a `CompilerInstance` the file you are passing is being treated as a compilation unit, so an attempt is made to resolve included headers and modules. You may want to have a look at the compilation settings used in Xcode to provide the standard modules like UIKit or Foundation.

Comment: That is correct, I'm just using the AppDelegate.m file that is generated when you create a new iOS project.